# Excel VBA: How to put formula in next available column for unique number of rows?

Tags: vba, excel, vlookup

I am still new to VBA and am trying to perform a vlookup in the next available column from row 4 until the used range for the vlookup is over. In addition, once the vlookup is completed, in the line under I need to sum all the values in the cells above. If that is confusing, here is the code I have so far:

```
 Sub vlookup2()
Dim SourceLastRow As Long
Dim OutputLastRow As Long
Dim sourceSheet As Worksheet
Dim outputSheet As Worksheet
Set sourceSheet = Worksheets("Data1")
Set outputSheet = Worksheets("Pivot")
With sourceSheet
     SourceLastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
End With
With outputSheet
    OutputLastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row
    .Range("*4:*" & OutputLastRow).Formula = _
         "=VLOOKUP(D4,'" & sourceSheet.Name & "'!$A$2:$H$" & SourceLastRow & ",3,0)"
End With
End Sub
```

Where I have the "*4: *" is where I'd imagine I need to put the data for the next available column. After that I would just need to sum everything from that column in the next available from in that column. Can someone please help?

Comment: What makes it the next available column, how's that determined?  Is it the next column from column A, to the right, that's empty?

Comment: that's what I was trying to ask, I have data from columns a to y right now, but that could change to columns a to m or something next month. It would just be the next available empty column

Comment: Sounds like you want the last used column, e.g., Dim LC as Long LC=Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column , then you would use that LC to determine where the vlookup searches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finds the next available column and inserts your formula in the range and sums it at the bottom. If your column count is greater than 26 then you need to modify it.

```
        Dim SourceLastRow As Long
        Dim OutputLastRow As Long
        Dim sourceSheet As Worksheet
        Dim outputSheet As Worksheet

        Dim NextColumn As Long
        Dim ColumnStr As String
         Dim ColumnStr2 As String
          Dim ColumnStr3 As String
        Set sourceSheet = Worksheets("Data1")
        Set outputSheet = Worksheets("Pivot")
        With sourceSheet
             SourceLastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        End With



        With outputSheet
            NextColumn = .Cells(4, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column + 1
            If NextColumn + 1 < 27 Then
               ColumnStr = Chr(64 + NextColumn + 1)
            Else
                ColumnStr = Chr(64 + Int((NextColumn + 1) / 26)) & Chr(64 + ((NextColumn + 1) Mod 26))
            End If
            If NextColumn - 1 < 27 Then
               ColumnStr3 = Chr(64 + NextColumn - 1)
            Else
                ColumnStr3 = Chr(64 + Int((NextColumn - 1) / 26)) & Chr(64 + ((NextColumn - 1) Mod 26))
            End If
            If NextColumn < 27 Then
               ColumnStr2 = Chr(64 + NextColumn)
            Else
                ColumnStr2 = Chr(64 + Int((NextColumn) / 26)) & Chr(64 + ((NextColumn) Mod 26))
            End If
            OutputLastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row

            .Range(Cells(4, NextColumn), Cells(OutputLastRow, NextColumn)).Formula = _
                 "=VLOOKUP(D4,'" & sourceSheet.Name & "'!$A$2:$H$" & SourceLastRow & ",3,0)" & "*" & ColumnStr3 & 4
            DoEvents
            .Cells(OutputLastRow + 1, NextColumn).Formula = "=SUM(" & ColumnStr2 & "4:" & ColumnStr2 & OutputLastRow & ")"
        End With
```

Comment: thank you, that worked! I just have one more modification I need from you that I left out. The vlookup outputs need to be multiplied by the column to the left of it. So the output values that are in the "available column" need to be multiplied by the values in the column prior to that one. In this example the vlookup outputs from your formula came out on column z, I need those values to be multiplied by the values in column y.

Comment: Ok this should do it.

Comment: Thank you, I just have a question, why/how do I have to modify it if it is more than 26 characters?

Comment: I included the modification with the last update. It is because once you get past Z it goes to AA. Then you are not able to simply pass the number in the CHR(64+i)(This will cover A to Z). You have to if i < 27 then : CHR(64+i): ELSE CHR(64+INT(i/26)) & CHR(64 + (i MOD 26): End IF. This will cover Columns A to ZZ.

Comment: I've been trying to play with your code, because although it works, multiplying column B with column A would get me the multiplied values in column C, When I need them in column B. After modifying the code to the best of my ability I am getting column B to multiply column A properly, but it ends up turning all the values to 0. Here are my slight modifications:

Comment: `OutputLastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row

        .Range(Cells(4, NextColumn), Cells(OutputLastRow, NextColumn)).Formula = _
             "=VLOOKUP(D4,'" & sourceSheet.Name & "'!$A$2:$H$" & SourceLastRow & ",6,0)"
        DoEvents
        .Range(Cells(4, NextColumn), Cells(OutputLastRow, NextColumn)).Formula = _
             "=" & ColumnStr3 & 4 & "*" & ColumnStr2 & 4
              DoEvents
        .Cells(OutputLastRow, NextColumn).Formula = "=SUM(" & ColumnStr & "4:" & ColumnStr & OutputLastRow & ")"
    End With`

Comment: I modified it so that the Vlookup and the multiplication are in the same column and then totals at the end.